# wget unable to download FTP link of FASTQ file on compute node of HPC cluster

Tags: wget, hpc

I have to download around 15k SRA files in FASTQ format for which I have the FTP links. The format for the same is below:

```
wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR848/002/SRR8482202/SRR8482202_1.fastq.gz'
```

When I run on my local system using Ubuntu22.04LTS, it runs and starts downloading the files. It even downloads the file on login node where, we should not execute a job, but when I write a bash script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR848/002/SRR8482202/SRR8482202_1.fastq.gz'
```

and run the job using qsub, it gives me the following error:

[image]

As per details on google it has something to do with hostadress IP, which we are strictly told to not change on HPC.

etc/resolv

[image]

I have tried using different formats of wget by using:

```
--no-dns-cache
--no-proxy
```

but nothing worked.

Comment: Your DNS servers are the computer itself and something in the private network, so there's no way for us to know if that's ok or not. But try for example 8.8.8.8 instead if it works for you. You can also check thing with nslookup. Also, no idea what is `qsub` and why you have tagged things that have nothing to do with network or DNS.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It's not unusual for HPC compute nodes to be configured with no external network access. You should check with your HPC sysadmin to see if this is the case for your cluster.

Comment: Please show error messages as texts, not images (screenshots)